# Is it possible to build separate CSS file with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

By default everything is bundled in:

- inline.bundle.js
- polyfills.bundle.js
- styles.bundle.js
- vendor.bundle.js
- main.bundle.js

Is it possible to have separate **CSS file**?

Comment: separation based upon what kind of criteria..?

Comment: CSS criteria :)

Comment: oh, you mean load the css files at runtime based on styleURLs ? (that sounds like a preformance killer)

Comment: no, just compile all css assets into one file, CSS file, not JS file.

Comment: that sounds against the angular component pattern... I don't think that's possible... But I guess you could do this if you skip angular-cli and create your own webpack-loader.

Comment: "against the angular component pattern" - that's true. Unfortunately I have to do it. To make possible to load different style-themes

Comment: @StepanSuvorov You met exactly the same situation as I now. I needed to use specific theme (from specific file) according to value in config.json file and, unfortunately, angular still doesn't support variable interpolation in SCSS \@import path, so this was the only possible way how to implement this...

Comment: The docs are terrible for loading multiple themes. There ought to be a standardized way. They actually suggest just changing the path of the css include to `/path/to/styles.css` with no further guidance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this using `--extract-css` flag of `ng build`. This is the default in `--prod` mode. More details here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: `--extract-css` IS Deprecated since version 11.0. No longer required to disable CSS extraction for HMR.

Answer (score 55):

Yes!  In your `angular.json` file the common thing to do is

```json
"styles": [
  "styles/bootstrap.scss",
  "styles/app.scss",
  "styles/whatever-else.scss"
]
```

and that all gets combined into a `dist/styles.5d56937b24df63b1d01d.css` file or whatever it decides to name it.

**INSTEAD** you can use [the object notation defined here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config)

```json
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "styles/bootstrap.scss",
    "bundleName": "bootstrap"
  },
  {
    "input": "styles/app.scss",
    "bundleName": "app"
  },
  {
    "input": "styles/whatever-else.scss",
    "bundleName": "foo-bar"
  },
]
```

and this will generate 3 separate CSS files:

- `dist/bootstrap.*.css`
- `dist/app.*.css`
- `dist/foo-bar.*.css`

Comment: Excellent I have read that wiki page numerous times, but missed the `object format` section!

Comment: @CBarr is there a way to get the hash url? because i dont know how i get the path for include it with js in <head> after the app gets initialized...

Comment: @CBarr , how can I switch between these bundles in runtime?

Comment: @Mironline I am not sure that would be possible to do, at least not simply. I'm not familiar with how that might be done if it is possible.

Comment: @Budi @Mironline if you include `inject: false`, the bundled css is not injected and the file is not hashed and can be loaded using any mean.

Answer (score 25):

As @Rob correctly pointed out you can use flag `--extract-css`. Unfortunately this flag is not possible to use with `ng-serve` from Angular 6+.

If you want to extract css in both `ng build` and `ng-serve` you can edit `angular.json` file in below section `architect -> build -> options` add new option `"extractCss": true`

Comment: Since version 11 `extractCss` is deprecated